# How to change pandas category type using a dtype dict?

Tags: pandas

Instead of doing:

```
for col in df.columns : 
   df[col]= df[col].astype('category')
```

I am doing this:

```
dtype0= {'brand': np.dtype('int64'),
 'category': np.dtype('int64'),
 'chain': np.dtype('int64'),
 'company': np.dtype('int64'),
 'date': np.dtype('O'),
 'dept':  pandas.types.dtypes.CategoricalDtype,
 'id': np.dtype('int64')}

df= df.astype(dtype0)
```

However, it does not work. Just wondering, how do I change into category using the dictionary?

Answer (score 38):

Previous answer is not correct. We can cast after creating the dataframe.

Solution is (for the record for other people stuck here):
Pandas 0.19.1

```
dtype0= {'brand': 'int64',
 'category': 'int64',
 'chain': 'int64',
 'company': 'int64',
 'date': 'str',
 'dept':  'category',
 'id': 'int64'}
df= df.astype(dtype0)
```

casting works here.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this. swap your dataframe name in this below pasted code.

```
column_datatype_dict = df_or.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.name).to_dict()
```

print(column_datatype_dict)

Answer (score -6):

you can only do that when you read in your data

```
data = pd.read_csv('mypath.csv', dtypes = mydict)
```

Comment: Wrong, please read the doc http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: @GurV A code-only answer might not be a good one, but it's still an answer. I would recommend you this post about the LQPRQ: [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)

Comment: 1) the answer is incorrect since the dataframe is not loaded from csv.... 2) 'only do that'  is also incorrect, since we can cast after creating the dataframe.   3) Maybe , I should just write , read the doc carefully...